# How make own style of UITextField without coding of each widget

Tags: ios, xcode, textfield

I want that all of my TextField elements on a screen have red border, some shadow & so on.
For one TextField I can set up this parameters in code of controller. Make outlet and set all parameters. 
But how to make own textfield where all of this parameters was setup before and no need to setup it for each instance of textfield manual?

Thanks.

Comment: Create your own subclass of `UITextField` and use that.

Comment: why don't you create method where you pass your textfield & set each values .

Comment: About method where I pass outlet with TextField - it's not a good idea. Because anyway need to make outlet, call method & so on.

Comment: @maddy it's interesting idea - can you illustrate it. Better in swift :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
class MySuperDuperTextField: UITextField {
     override func awakeFromNib() { // if you're not using Storyboards, you should override initWithFrame: or come up with your own init
         // stylize here...
         layer.borderColor = .redColor().CGColor // red border
     }
}
```

There are lots of approaches to shadows, it's better if you look that up and pick a solution that works well for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should maybe create an extension class and have each of your different textfields in there and they will be reusable anywhere you `#import "UITextField+Extensions.h"`

UITextField+Extensions .h file

```
@interface UIColor (SPQExtensions)

+(UITextField *)shadowTextFieldWithFrame:(CGRect)frame;

@end
```

UITextField+Extensions .m file

```
@implementation UITextField (Extensions)

+(UITextField *)shadowTextFieldWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    UITextField *textfield = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:frame];

    // rest of your setup code

    return textfield;
}

@end
```